# 'issubclass() arg 2 must be a class or tuple of classes' error in gridsearchCV

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, random-forest, gridsearchcv

i have the following training dataset:

```
>>> x_train.head()

    macd        obv         topbolly    lowbolly    st_osc
0   0.419159    0.053660    0.013555    0.026964    0.687500
1   0.437048    0.104123    0.014081    0.027093    0.887500
2   0.440777    0.071029    0.013986    0.026800    0.591549
3   0.427528    0.088902    0.013755    0.026715    0.718310
4   0.422571    0.075212    0.013386    0.026610    0.676056

931 rows × 5 columns
```

and following target values:

```
>>> y_train

0      15.580000
1      15.290000
2      15.380000
3      15.350000
4      15.360000
         ...    
926    29.690001
927    28.750000
928    29.510000
929    29.570000
930    29.059999
Name: close, Length: 931, dtype: float64
```

none of the cells are empty. when i'm trying to do following gridsearchCV, i'm getting the error:

```
clf=GridSearchCV (RandomForestRegressor(), {'n_estimators':[5,10,100,500,1000],'min_samples_leaf':[3,5,7]}, return_train_score=False, cv=3)
clf.fit(x_train,y_train)
resultscvdf=pd.DataFrame(clf.cv_results_)
```

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-266-da2a03deeaac> in <module>
      1 clf=GridSearchCV(RandomForestRegressor(), {'n_estimators':[5,10,100,500,1000],'min_samples_leaf':[3,5,7]}, return_train_score=False, cv=3)
----> 2 clf.fit(x_train,y_train)
      3 resultscvdf=pd.DataFrame(clf.cv_results_)
      4 resultscvdf

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
    686                 return results
    687 
--> 688             self._run_search(evaluate_candidates)
    689 
    690         # For multi-metric evaluation, store the best_index_, best_params_ and

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in _run_search(self, evaluate_candidates)
   1147     def _run_search(self, evaluate_candidates):
   1148         """Search all candidates in param_grid"""
-> 1149         evaluate_candidates(ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))
   1150 
   1151 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in evaluate_candidates(candidate_params)
    683                 nonlocal results
    684                 results = self._format_results(
--> 685                     all_candidate_params, scorers, n_splits, all_out)
    686                 return results
    687 

TypeError: issubclass() arg 2 must be a class or tuple of classes
```

can somebody please help me out in telling what's wrong here?

Comment: I run your code and It works for me! Which version of sklearn do you have?

Comment: @DavideBrex Version 0.21.3

Comment: Try to update to 0.22.2. I hope this solves the issue. Are you sure there are no Nan in your dataframes?

Comment: it worked on updating. thanks a lot !